# Why is this identity true very confusing.

Tags: calculus

$-\dfrac{x}{y}\dfrac{dy}{dt}=y\dfrac{d}{dt}\bigg(\dfrac{x}{y}\bigg)-\dfrac{dx}{dt}
$

If I try to work out the right side I get $\dfrac{y}{y}\dfrac{dx}{dt}-\dfrac{dx}{dt}+yx\dfrac{d}{dt}\dfrac{1}{y}$

or if I take the $1/y$ outside and put the $y$ inside I get the + version of the left hand side. How is this correct this is in a book.

Comment: What's here a function of what?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are functions of $t$

Comment: You did not apply properly the quotient rule for $\dfrac{d}{dt}\bigg(\dfrac{x}{y}\bigg)$

Comment: I noticed. It is a very late night.

Comment: That identity is very very unmotivated. I would of never have thought of to write out the left hand side like that.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Well, he *did* properly apply the product rule to $\frac{x}{y}=x\cdot\frac{1}{y}$, he just didn't then calculate $\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{y}$ which would immediately have given the left side.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a rearrangement of
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac xy\right)=\frac{y\frac d{dt} x-x\frac d{dt}y}{y^2}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming both $\;x,y\;$ are functions of $\;t\;$ , on the right side we have :

$$y\frac d{dt}\left(\frac xy\right)-x'\stackrel{\text{Quotient rule}}=y\frac{x'y-xy'}{y^2}-x'=\require{cancel} \cancel{x'}-\frac{xy'}y-\cancel{x'}=\color{red}{-\frac{xy'}y}$$

and on the left side:

$$-\frac xyy'=\color{red}{-\frac{xy'}y}$$

Comment: The chain rule... I am lacking too much sleep

Comment: Well, not so much the chain rule as the quotient rule for derivatives.

Comment: @DonAntonio I've always thought about the quotient rule in terms of the product rule and the chain rule.